# CTLR + C interrupt signal in python causes raise KeyboardInterrupt("Execution interrupted")

Tags: python, signals, python-3.6

I have the following code running on Python 3.9.0 on a windows 10 machine.

Plan is to exit from the while loop and exit gracefully,It should print some message here 'hello'and exit.

```
import signal # Import signal module using the import keyword
import time

# available signalson our System
valid_signals = signal.valid_signals() #requires python3.9.0
print(valid_signals)

#create a Signal Handler
def SignalHandler(SignalNumber,Frame):
    print('hello')
    print(f'Signal Number -> {SignalNumber} Frame -> {Frame} ')
    
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,SignalHandler)

while 1:  
    print("Press Ctrl + C") 
    time.sleep(1)
```

When i run this, **I am getting this KeyboardInterrupt: Execution interrupted**
**strong text**
here is the output of the script

```
Python 3.9.0 (C:\Python\python.exe)
>>> %Run Python-.py
{<Signals.SIGINT: 2>, <Signals.SIGILL: 4>, <Signals.SIGFPE: 8>, <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>, <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>, <Signals.SIGBREAK: 21>, <Signals.SIGABRT: 22>}
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\_1_Personal\MY PROJECTS\SourceCodes\Python3-Tutorial\Python-.py", line 18, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
  File "C:\Thonny\lib\site-packages\thonny\backend.py", line 346, in signal_handler
    raise KeyboardInterrupt("Execution interrupted")
KeyboardInterrupt: Execution interrupted
>>>
```

**Why is the code not going to the Signal handler** and printing hello?

Comment: Code works for me -  after `{<Signals.SIGINT: 2>, <Signals.SIGILL: 4>, <Signals.SIGFPE: 8>, <Signals.SIGSEGV: 11>, <Signals.SIGTERM: 15>, <Signals.SIGBREAK: 21>, <Signals.SIGABRT: 22>}` I get mutliple `Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C
hello
Signal Number -> 2 Frame -> <frame at 0x000001CA6E67FC60, file 'c:\\Users\\*****\\t.py', line 17, code <module>>
Press Ctrl + C
hello
Signal Number -> 2 Frame -> <frame at 0x000001CA6E67FC60, file 'c:\\Users\\*****\\t.py', line 17, code <module>>
Press Ctrl + C
Press Ctrl + C`

Comment: @PatrickArtner which IDE are you using.I am using thonny

Comment: VS code - maybe start your file in a console using "python3  yourfile.py" to test.

Comment: @PatrickArtner works with python on command line no issue

Answer (score 1):

Issue was with the  IDE ,Thonny and IDLE
When i tried running the code on command line directly,

C:> python Abovepythoncode.py

No issues were found

Comment: Glad it worked out :)

Answer (score 0):

try this and put your code in `try` block, And when you press CTRL + C then exception will occure

```
try:
    # main code here
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print ('KeyboardInterrupt exception is caught')
else:
    print ('No exceptions are caught')
```

Comment: That is not the point. The point is the module `signal`  provides the ability to create and register  a sig-handler that is called when the signal occurs:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html#signal.signal